# Paypal "we were unable to decrypt the certificate ID'

Tags: php, encryption, paypal

I'm trying to integrate a PayPal button into my site, using a method found here:
[How-To: Build your own PayPal Encrypted Buttons](http://www.stellarwebsolutions.com/en/articles/paypal_button_encryption_php.php)

I followed all the instructions, but when I click the button on my page, it goes to a page that says `We were unable to decrypt the certificate id.`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First - you have to go look at:

http://blog.scrobbld.com/paypal/protecting-your-payments-with-ewp/

Then you will need:

http://www.flatmtn.com/article/setting-openssl-create-certificates

After you have set all of the above up you need to go to PayPal and log in.  Click on the "use classic interface" button because it is easier to use.  Once you are at your main PayPal location make sure the left most tab is clicked on and is active.  Under the tabs you will see the "Profile" link. Hover your mouse over it (or you may have to left click it).  You should see a drop down menu.  At the bottom it says "My Selling Tools".  Click on it.  On the right hand side you should see the "API access" and a link.  Click on that to set your API settings if you need them.  At the VERY BOTTOM of the "My Selling Tools" web page is the "Encrypted payment settings" link.  Click on it.  IF YOU DON'T SEE a certificate at the bottom - then you need to make one.  The CERTIFICATE ID will be on the left.  You need to put that in to your call to the setCertificateID() function.  From the PayPalEWP class.

Be sure to read all of the comments on the first website.  They are important!

I hope this helps. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you try to solve this error " "**we were unable to decrypt ...**" then you can solve this way
I think you cannot do right configurations of your sandbox
click [here](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/buttons) for creating a add to cart button then
after creating button then show you some script copy paste in your project

e.g

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" >
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="Your email here all notification send on this email">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="webTest">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="12.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="2.000">
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="3.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
```